# How to renew ssl certificate for exchange 2007?

Tags: ssl-certificate, exchange-2007

My certificate expired thus I bought a new one. When I go to configure(put the csr in) the panel of my ssl provider, I get the following error:

```
Common name is already present in a current certificate.
```

I think because the old certificate is still installed. Maybe to solve the problem I have to renew the old one, but how?
If I type:

```
Get-ExchangeCertificate -thumbprint xxxxxx | New-ExchangeCertificate
```

would this work?

When I do this though, I'm asked if it can overwrite the old certificate?!?!?
This new certificate expires in 3 years... but the procedure to renew it expires only in 1 year...

Comment: "I think because the old certificate is still installed" <-- No, it means exactly what it says. You've entered a CN that is already present in a certificate that is not expired or about to expire (typically 14-30 days before expiration). "but with the procedure to renew it expires only in 1 year." <-- The wat are you talking about???

Comment: Sorry, my english is terrible. Well, the installed certificate was expired yesterday. Today I bought a new one. I am in the control panel of the ssl provider and I have to put the csr (this is a NEW csr) in the form. When I click the next button it gives me the error.  In the csr I inserted che cn=mailserver.mycompany.com and in the san autodiscover.mycompany.com. With the "but with the procedure to renew it expires only in 1 year" I am talking about the procedure to renew csr by get-exchangecertificate | new-exchangecertificate

Answer (score 1):

If you've already bought a new one, import it and then unbind the Exchange services (SMTP, etc.) bound to the old one and then bind them to the new one.

It's pretty straightforward, really no different than when you setup the original cert, but you can follow the Technet articles below:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124424%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997231%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997569.aspx

Comment: I have payed a new one, but I have not still created, because the ssl provider don't accept my csr.